# How to disable highlight on an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to disable highlight on an image, when I drag my mouse over an image, it is highlighted.
Take a look:
[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is the top result on google for some searches. I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5225928/645270) is what many of you are looking for!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS rule to disable text selection highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
img {
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: @Phil You could edit your answer, so it's no longer incorrect. There are heavy discussions about deleting accepted answers and why it shouldn't be deleted. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272849/please-allow-me-to-delete-my-own-accepted-answer

Answer (score 57):

Use [user-select](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-css3-userint-20000216#user-select) property:

```
img{
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest method as of today. Also, for anyone looking for a way to disable odd effects in images like I was, take a look at the `draggable` attribute. Setting it to `false` in the img tag will avoid the ghost image should the user accidentally (or not) drag it.

Answer (score 14):

You can try this (this won't work in all browsers):

```
img::-moz-selection {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #000;
}

img::selection {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #000;
}
```

Or you can use a `<div>` with the appropriate width and height set and use a CSS background image on it. For example I use this on my site:

```
<div id="header"></div>

#header {
    height: 79px;
    width: 401px;
    background: url(http://nclabs.org/images/header.png) no-repeat;
}
```

And finally you can use Javascript to programatically disable it.

Comment: 2019 already, and the selection pseudo-selector is now the best solution.

Answer (score 6):

This disabled highlighting on a DOM element:

```
function disableSelection(target){
    if (typeof target.onselectstart!="undefined") // if IE
        target.onselectstart=function(){return false}
    else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect!="undefined") // if Firefox
        target.style.MozUserSelect="none";
    else // others
        target.onmousedown=function(){return false;}

    target.style.cursor = "default";
}
```

Use it like this:

```
disableSelection(document.getElementById("my_image"));
```

Comment: Great Technique, solved for android webview. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try to put it as a css background instead of an img element.

Answer (score 3):

```
img{
   -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
   -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
   -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
   user-select: none;          /* Likely future */      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the selection of text and images from entire website use body selector

```
body {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing a problem when you click on the image, here is the solution to that.

```
img {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

if not working then please try that in your parent of the image that contains the whole width of the image.

Answer (score 0):

In case some people here are interested about the sass mixin:

```
// Prevent users to select an element
@mixin no-select {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```