# How to remove selection on images

Tags: html, css, image, selection, selectall

I want to remove the selection-highlight on all images on my page. 
I found some useful additions like :

CSS

```
img {
     -webkit-user-select:none;
     -khtml-user-select:none;
     -moz-user-select:none;
     -o-user-select:none;
      user-select:none;
      pointer-events:none
}
```

But when I press down my mouse button and select multiple things or press `Ctrl+A` for "select all" my images get highlighted with a blue shade.
I tried to change it via :

CSS

```
img::selection      {background:transparent;color:inherit;}
img::-moz-selection {background:transparent;color:inherit;}
```

But that don't have any effect.

Does someone have a useful solution or is there none yet ?

P.S. : I don't care about selecting my images - I just want to get rid of that blue shape.

Comment: Try adding the style: outline:0

Comment: forgot to mention - tested it already and as you can imagine - won't work

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/zsbhczkk/](http://jsfiddle.net/zsbhczkk/) Chrome is ok

Comment: IE is also OK.... so this means that's it's a Firefox issue

Comment: @Pinal - this wont work for FF and IE on my device

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816080/how-to-disable-highlight-on-a-image for more info

Answer (score 1):

Here goes a wacky solution I came up with...

1) After some testing I found that this only occurs on mozilla. Other browsers don't show the blue selection on images when the code

```
img::selection {
    background: transparent;
}
```

is set.

2) Even mozilla - only has a problem with image elements. But other elements with a `background-image` obey the `::selection` rule.

So *technically* we could work around this assuming we add an empty span in our markup after each img element which we set to display:none;

Then we can add some CSS which will only run in firefox which sets the images to `display:none` and places a background-image on the adjacent span.

Like this:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GMuzV/30/)**

**

```css
img::selection {
    background: transparent;
}
img + span {
    display: none;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    img {
        display: none;
    }
    
    img + span {
        background: url(http://placehold.it/200x200) no-repeat;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div>Hello there </div>

<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /><span></span>

<div>Hello there </div>
```

[1](http://jsfiddle.net/GMuzV/30/): http://jsfiddle.net/GMuzV/30/

Comment: Well it works nice - sadly I forgot to mention I need the <img> tag itself for SEO purposes. If no other solution is found today - you'll get the bounty reward for your research and work tho ;)

Comment: I wasn't proposing to eliminate the img elements. My solution proposes to just set `display:none` on them, and also - only for forefox. This should not interfere with SEO because the markup remains pretty much the same (except for the extra span)

Comment: Do you really think that google-bots are not able to lower your SEO, since key elements are on display:none; or visibility:hidden; ? Then why people have big visible tagclouds or footer ?

Answer (score 0):

This disabled highlighting on a DOM element:

```
function disableSelection(target){
    if (typeof target.onselectstart!="undefined") // if IE
        target.onselectstart=function(){return false}
    else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect!="undefined") // if Firefox
        target.style.MozUserSelect="none";
    else // others
         target.onmousedown=function(){return false;}

    target.style.cursor = "default";
}
```

Use it like this:

```
disableSelection(document.getElementById("my_image"));
```

Comment: I appriciate your work, but Firefox still messes up with that code :/