# How to disable all mouse events in a web page in HTML or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I place the text on the image inside the label. If I drag the text and place it in a text box it automatically copies that text. But i don't want that to be happened. Please give me a hint to disable the mouse click and drag event on the text.

Comment: Have a look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439042/css-js-to-prevent-dragging-of-ghost-image

Answer (score 6):

this help you :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <span id="txt" draggable="false">This is test</span>
    <script>
        var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
         txt.addEventListener("click",function(event){event.preventDefault();})
        txt.addEventListener("mousedown",function(event){event.preventDefault();})
         txt.addEventListener("mouseup",function(event){event.preventDefault();})
          txt.addEventListener("contextmenu",function(event){event.preventDefault();})
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't have that privilege.. I need to earn 15 reputation for that  but i did not earn yet ...